# Boostrap Collapse - Focus Top Area

Tags: javascript, php, twitter-bootstrap-3

I need your help.

I have three bootstrap collapse buttons and I want to focus the top area after clicking the button.

This is the code:

```
<div class="wrapperbuttonsrooms" style="margin-top: -30px;">
<button type="button" class="buttonroominfo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo<?php echo $room['rateCode'];?>">Room Amenities</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonroominfo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#zweite<?php echo $room['rateCode'];?>">Room Description</button>
<button type="button" class="buttonroominfo" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#dritte<?php echo $room['rateCode'];?>">Check-in Instructions</button>
<div id="demo<?php echo $room['rateCode'];?>" class="panel-body collapse fade">
   <?php include 'amenities-max.php';?>
</div>
<div id="zweite<?php echo $room['rateCode'];?>" class="panel-body collapse fade">
   <p style="font-size:17px;"> <b>Room Description:</b></p>
   <p><?php echo $room['RoomType']['descriptionLong']; ?></p>
</div>
<div id="dritte<?php echo $room['rateCode'];?>" class="panel-body collapse fade">
   <p style="font-size:17px;"><b>Special Check-in Instructions:</b></p>
   <br> 
   <p><?php echo @$specialCheckInInstructions; ?>   </p>
   <p><?php echo @$checkInInstructions; ?></p>
</div>
```

How can I achieve that?